# Python - Import from deeper subfolder

Tags: python, python-import, directory-structure

Somehow I couldn't find the exact answer to this elsewhere on SO.

Given:

```
root\
    __init__.py
    main.py
    folder0\
        __init__.py
        folder1\
             __init__.py
             class1.py
        folder2\
             __init__.py
             class2.py
```

Is there a way to import the top level directory as a whole? e.g.

```
# main.py
import folder0
obj1 = folder0.folder1.class1.Class1()
obj2 = folder0.folder2.class2.Class2()
```

Or do I have to import the modules directly? e.g.

```
# main.py
from folder0.folder1 import class1
from folder0.folder2 import class2
obj1 = class1.Class1()
obj2 = class2.Class2()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  You just need to add the relevant imports into the `__init__.py` all the way down.  e.g.:

```
# folder2/__init__.py
from . import class2
```

and

```
# folder0/__init__.py
from . import folder1
from . import folder2
```

and so-on.